# Emulating rotations around pivot in SVG

Tags: math, svg, computational-geometry

I am trying to emulate a pivot rotation(rotate an element around a certain point, instead around it's center), on an SVG group element.

I have at my dispense only 2 tools:

- A function that can move an element to an x-y direction in steps.
  Let's call this `moveElement(x,y);`
- Another function that can rotate the element around it's center in
  steps. Let's call this `setRotationAngle(angle);`

I've tried doing this with the formula below, to no avail.

```
setRotationAngle(angle)
step_x = cos(angle) * (element.x - x) - sin(angle) * (element.y - y)
step_y = sin(angle) * (element.x - x) + cos(angle) * (element.y - y)
moveElement( step_x, step_y)
```

I know that this can be done using the transformation center rotations that already exist in the spec, but unfortunately I cannot use those as I don't want to change the transformation center of the element.

I am looking to do this using only the functions above, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, what you need to do is this:

```
moveElement(-centerX, -centerY);
rotateElement(angle);
moveElement(centerX, centerY);
```

Comment: If you want to rotate an object around an arbitrary center of rotation (centerX, centerY), then what I have written above is how you break down the sequence of transformations required to do that.